# Issue ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, matplotlib, astropy

I have a file with a table. I am trying to plot a velDisp vs. ABSMAG. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.io.fits import getdata
from astropy.table import Table

data = getdata("Subset.fits")
data, hdr = getdata("Subset.fits",1,header = True)

table = fits.open('Subset.fits')
data1 = Table(table[1].data)
#print("Columnns:", data1[0].columns)

graph = Table.read('Subset.fits')

mag = data1['ABSMAG']
r_mag = mag[:,2]

x = graph['ABSMAG']
y = graph['velDisp']

plt.scatter(x, y, color = 'r')
plt.title('Velocity Dispersion vs Absolute Magnitude')
plt.xlabel('Abs Mag(r_band)')
plt.ylabel('Velocity Dispersion')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

It's giving me the error that x and y must be the same size.The velDisp I believe is in 3D so this may need to be done in log space. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried doing len(x) and len(y) to confirm that they are the same length? Might be something to do with the way astropy reads missing data?

Comment: Yes they are the same length.

Comment: Please give the full traceback, since it's not clear where the error is occurring.